# Пропадают комментарии при добавлении GET-параметров

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Можно ли настроить виджет комментариев `ВКонтакте` так, чтобы комментарии не пропадали при добавлении `GET`-параметров в адрес страницы?

Comment: _какие_ и _зачем_ гет параметры вы отправляете?

Comment: @ThisMan, например, если на странице присутствует компонент переключения страниц (`pagination`) - при нажатии на кнопку в адрес добавляется параметр типа `?page=2`, и комментарии VK перестают отображаться.

Comment: а апи вообще поддерживает такие параметры? может не правильно ссылку составляете

Comment: @ThisMan, что значит "составляете ссылку"?

Comment: ну вы же куда-то гет параметры добавляете, значит, как то адрес собираете

Comment: @ThisMan, `CMS` делает это автоматически. Имеется компонент списка отзывов, и под ним размещен список комментариев `VK`. У основных комментариев сайта есть переключатель страниц, и вот, при переходе на другую страницу теряются комментарии `VK` (на странице без параметров они отображаются нормально).

Comment: сложно так сказать тогда, может компонент сломан, может ссылка не правильная. Нужные конкретные данные, иначе на кофейной гуще гадаем

Comment: @ThisMan, у вас есть опыт нормальной работы компонента на странице с `get`-параметрами и без них - так, будто, это одна и та же страница?

Answer (score 0):

Для таких вещей нужно изначально использовать в виджете page_id (это произвольное число, которое указывается последним в вызове VK.Widgets.Comments, после фигурных скобок), чтобы на страницах с разными параметрами page_id совпадал и комментарии были одинаковыми. Вы, скорее всего, обошлись без page_id.

Итак, остается только одно, довольно костыльное решение. Это параметр pageUrl, который указывается тоже в VK.Widgets.Comments, только внутри фигурных скобок, и содержит старый адрес страницы с комментариями.

Например, так:

VK.Widgets.Comments("vk_comments", {limit: 20, width: "960", attach: "*", pageUrl: "здесь адрес страницы"});